# How to execute a PowerShell command that includes double quotes

Tags: java, powershell

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell command (from JavaFx) to obtain a device driver version.

My problem is some double quotes included in the PS cmdlet.

Running the command

`Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -like "*selectedDeviceName*"}`,

directly in PS gives me the result I'm expecting to get. But (after numerous trial & errors and googling) I'm confused about how to handle the double quotes included in the cmdlet.

Here is the JavaFx method in which the PS cmdlet is embedded:

```
public void getDriverVersionViaPowerShell() {

ProcessBuilder psProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe",

"Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion| where {$_.devicename -like "*selectedDeviceName*"}");


//some code...
}
```

The `"*selectedDeviceName*"` part is my problem. `selectedDeviceName` is a string variable that contains the name of the device whose driver version I'm trying to get.

I would be glad to get some help to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your time and help !!!

AvJoe

Answer (score 0):

```
"Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion| where {$_.devicename -like \"" + selectedDeviceName +"\"}"
```

You can use `\` as escape character for including double quotes in string.
Output would be:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion| where {$_.devicename -like "name of the driver"}
```

Comment: Snippets are for runnable HTML/JavaScript snippets. Please do not use them for other code.

Comment: Pasting a snapshot of code would be helpful? Snippets make it easier to understand.

Comment: Again, snippets have a very distinct purpose. Do not use them for other things. Regular code can be formatted via the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow this going forward.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers
Thanks for your help!!! PS executes the code but with error:
Unexpected token 'YXZ' in expression or statement. And I have no idea why